# Log rotate is not working in Centos 6.6 MongoDB 3.2.12

Tags: mongodb, logging, centos

I installed mongoDB 3.2.12 in my linux machine Centos 6.6, Log rotate is not working and i have placed my configuration files here below . Can anyone help me on that?

`/etc/logrotate/mongodb`

```
/var/log/mongodb/*.log { 
  daily
  size 10K
  rotate 1
  compress
  dateext
  delaycompress
  copytruncate
  notifempty
  postrotate
    /bin/kill -SIGUSR1 `cat /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true  
  endscript
}
```

mongod.conf

```
logAppend: true  
logRotate: reopen
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case my logrotate file was here `/etc/logrotate.d/mongod` with following:

```
/var/log/mongodb/*.log {
  daily
  missingok
  rotate 5
  compress
  dateext
  delaycompress
  copytruncate
  notifempty
}
```

So it appears that your path to logrotate config is incorrect. You listed `/etc/logrotate/mongodb` but I am pretty sure it should be `/etc/logrotate.d/mongod`. Your `mongod.conf` appear to be same as mine. Also i had to test that logs are rotated correctly by manually issuing logrotate command:

```
logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/mongod
```

Comment: Is the path on CentOS 7 different?  I am not seeing anything in /etc/logrotate.d for mongod